# Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange. Due to: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization

Tags: sales

I am trying to setup Salesforce connection with VS code . Getting below error when trying to authorize :

Could not retrieve the username after successful auth code exchange. Due to: The REST API is not enabled for this Organization.

I am using Salesforce Developer edition trial version .

Answer (score 1):

On our project we were enabling API for particular user profile under which you are working

1. Click on Setup.
2. Go to Manage Users and click Profiles
3. Click Edit on the specific profile you're updating.
4. Scroll down to Administrative Permissions and check the API Enabled box.
5. Click Save.